# How to place text on the second page of the frontmatter in ConTeXt?

Tags: page-breaking, context, context-mkiv, front-matter

I need to put the copyright text on the second page of my ConTeXt document, on the verso page. I am using `\startfrontmatter` and `\startstandardmakeup` to create the title and authorship pages in the front matter. I tried three ways to add the copyright to the second page, but each failed:

```
\starttext
    \startfrontmatter
        \setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided, state=stop]
        \startstandardmakeup
            Title
            \page[left] Copyright (a) % on first page
        \stopstandardmakeup
            \page[left] Copyright (b) % on fourth page
        \startstandardmakeup
            \page[left] Copyright (c) % on fifth page
        \stopstandardmakeup
        \startstandardmakeup
            Author
        \stopstandardmakeup
    \stopfrontmatter
    \startbodymatter
    \stopbodymatter
\stoptext
```

How can I place text on the second page of my document?

Comment: The standard makeup comes with its own page break which defaults to the next recto page. With ``\setupmakeup[standard][page=yes]`` it moves forward only one page. (You will have to remove your manual breaks.)

Comment: The page option control whether the standard makeup starts from an odd or even page (or either). But, by default, a makeup assumes that one is working with a doublesided document and also inserts a page after the current page. To disable that, one has to use `doublesided=no`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, the `standard` makeup assumes that you are working with a double-sided document and want each page to start on the right. You have two options:

1. Redefine the standard makeup to use a single-sided layout, and start each page on any side:

   ```
   \setupmakeup[standard][page=yes, doublesided=no]
   ```
2. Define a new makeup that inherits all parameters from `standard` makeup, but changes the value of `page` and `doublesided`. This will allow you to use `standard` makeup in other parts of your document.

   ```
   \definemakeup[anypage][page=yes, doublesided=no]
   ```

   You can then use this as `\startanypagemakeup` ... `\stopanypagemakeup`.

Here is a minimal example using the first suggestion:

```
\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided]
\setupmakeup[standard][page=yes, doublesided=no]
\starttext
    \startfrontmatter
        \startstandardmakeup
            Title
        \stopstandardmakeup
        \startstandardmakeup
           \copyright \currentdate[year]
        \stopstandardmakeup
        \startstandardmakeup
            Author
        \stopstandardmakeup
    \stopfrontmatter
\stoptext
```