# How to obtain formatted page number in ConTeXt?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, context, framed, roman-numerals

## Problem

The `\pagenumber` macro does not reflect the `conversion` attribute value within the context of front matter vs. body matter. The front matter uses Roman numerals, the body matter uses regular text.

## Code

A minimum working example to show the problem:

```
\setuppapersize[letter][letter]

% See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128858/2148
\setuplayout[
  % Allow text to be flush with the top
  topspace=\zeropoint,
  % Stretch the text to its maximum (to place page number at very bottom)
  height=fit,
  % Allow text to be flush with the bottom
  footerdistance=\zeropoint,
]

  \setupcolors[state=start]

\definecolor[colourhighlight][h=F5F6CE]
\definecolor[colourtocseparator][colourtertiary]

% Use Roman numerals for the front matter
\definestructureconversionset[frontpart:pagenumber] [] [romannumerals]

% Put a coloured box around the page number
\setuppagenumbering[
  command={\inframed[
    frame=no,
    background=color,
    backgroundcolor=colourhighlight,
    width=2em,
    height=2em,
  ]{\pagenumber}},
]

  % Right-align the page number in the footer and assume single-sided pages
  \setuppagenumbering[location={footer,right,margin},alternative=singlesided]

  % Do not define a double-sided document environment.
  % See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122349/2148
  \setupmakeup[standard][page=yes, doublesided=no]

\starttext
\startfrontmatter
  \setuppagenumbering[conversion=romannumerals]
  \setcounter[userpage][1]

  % Title page (front cover)
  \startstandardmakeup
    Title page
  \stopstandardmakeup

  % Copyright page
  \startstandardmakeup
    Copyright
  \stopstandardmakeup

  % Table of Contents
  \completecontent
\stopfrontmatter

\startbodymatter
  \setuppagenumbering[conversion=numbers]
  \setcounter[userpage][2]

  \startchapter[
    title={chapter},
    reference=sec:chapter,
  ]

  \input knuth

  \stopchapter

\stopbodymatter

\stoptext
```

## Actual Results

The output for the front matter shows the normal page number (this is not desirable: it should be a roman numeral) beside the page number converted to a Roman numeral:

[image: Front Matter Page Number]

The output for the body matter shows the normal page number (this is desirable) beside the page number converted to a regular number:

[image: Body Matter Page Number]

## Expected Results

I was expecting the page number to keep the context of the conversion value, thus showing up as a roman numeral within the `\inframed` macro. I am trying to accomplish the following in the front matter:

[image: Roman Numeral within Inline Frame]

If possible, I'd rather avoid creating a layer.

## Question

How can you create a page number in a `\framed` (or `\inframed`) that is formatted according to the conversion value specified by:

```
\setuppagenumbering[conversion=romannumerals]
```

## Related

- [Eliminate topspace and bottomspace in ConTeXt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128854/eliminate-topspace-and-bottomspace-in-context)

Comment: Try to create more minimal examples next time and remove unnecessary settings like `\setuppapersize`, `\setupcolors` and the makeups. A minimal example for your problem would be: `\setupuserpagenumber[numberconversion=romannumerals]\starttext\pagenumber\stoptext`

Comment: For different conversion of page number in front part and bodypart see this [mailinglist post](http://tug.org/pipermail/texhax/2012-March/019038.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short Answer

Change `\pagenumber` to `\userpagenumber`.

### Expanation

Lets see what is happening here. Run `context --pipe` and type

```
*\show\pagenumber
> \pagenumber=macro:
->\strc_counters_raw \s!userpage .
```

So, `\pagenumber` gives the **raw** value of the counter `\s!userpage`.

On the other hand,

```
*\show\userpagenumber
> \userpagenumber=macro:
->\directconvertedcounter \s!userpage \empty .
```

so `\userpagenumber` gives the **converted** value of the counter `\s!userpage`.